# Why does my page content start off the screen then adjust down?

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin

I experience this issue only my Xamarin iOS project. The Android version works correctly.

I have a standard ContentPage that is pushed via PushAsync. When the page loads, the content loads off the screen then (it seems) after binding is finished moves down the page. I have attached a screen where it shows loading off the screen and one where it re-adjusts.
[Content off the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQhym.png)

[After binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i03zn.png)

XAML File

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <Frame Padding="10"
               Margin="20, 20, 20, 20"
               BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional">

            <StackLayout Margin="10">
                <Label Text="{Binding OutreachTitle}"
                       FontSize="Title"
                       TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryTextColor}"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                <controls:HorizontalRuleControl RuleColor="{StaticResource SecondaryColor}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding OutreachText}"
                       Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"
                       TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryTextColor}"
                       VerticalOptions="End"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not reproduced the problem on my side. While I would recommend you to use StackLayout  instead of AbsoluteLayout.

The problem is probably caused by resize of `View` in ContentPage, when you set `SizeProportional` of `AbsoluteLayout`, the size will following the changing of the View and that would cause the content loads off the screen:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Frame Padding="10"
           Margin="20, 20, 20, 20"
           BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <StackLayout Margin="10">
            <Label Text="{Binding OutreachTitle}"
                   FontSize="Title"
                   TextColor="Yellow"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <Label Text="{Binding OutreachText}"
                   Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"
                   TextColor="Green"
                   VerticalOptions="End"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I changed it to StackLayout as you suggested, but received the same result. Thanks for your idea.

Comment: Can you please share me the code where you navigate the page? Why the tabbar is visible after you navigate to a new page? I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: I am using a Shell and lazy-loading for my navigation. The calling method to push this page is as follows:

`await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () =>
                {
                    Preferences.Set("SelectedOutreachTitle", SelectedOutreach.OutreachTitle);
                    Preferences.Set("SelectedOutreachText", SelectedOutreach.OutreachText);

                    await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new OutreachPage());
                });`

Comment: No, I still  can't reproduce the issue. I use your layout in the CatDetailPage in official sample [xaminals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-xaminals/) and it works well.